# Screen Resolution Choices

Tags: 16.04, display-resolution

`16.04` is installed on an `Optiplex 390`, outfitted with a 1600 x 900 monitor.

The display setting options are: 1024 x 768 and 800 x 600.  Is it reasonable to expect the system to detect and offer the monitor's resolution?

What can be done to enable / unlock a 1600 x 900 resolution option?

Comment: Do you have a nVidia graphic card installed? Maybe you can try 18.04.1 LiveUSB first, to see if it can pump it up to 1600 x 900

Comment: Clever idea to try the 18.04 live USB.   No graphic card installed (motherboard has video controller).